# Stop firing a click event after the attributes on the element is dynamically changed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a link in my HTML and a Javascript `click` event handler which fires an Ajax request and changes its attributes based on the returned data.

I want to fire the click event only when `data-method` attribute of the link is `post`. Right now the event is fired even after its attributes are changed and the selector doesn't match anything.

How could I achieve this?

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="like-btn">
    <a class="like" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/">
      <i class="icon-clap"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  $('.sidebar .like-btn .like').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    $.ajax({
      url: /resource_likes,
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'POST',
      success: (data) => {
        $('.sidebar .like-btn a').attr({
            class: '',
            href: `/resource_likes/${data.like_id}`,
        })
        $('.sidebar .like-btn a').attr('data-method', 'delete')
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: If the HTML sets `data=method="post"`, and the click should only happen when `data-method="delete"`, how will you ever call the AJAX function that changes it to `delete`? Did you describe it backwards?

Comment: Oh sorry it's backwards. Thank you for catching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to check the attribute in the event handler.

```
$('.sidebar .like-btn .like').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    if ($(this).attr("data-method") != "post") {
      return;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: /resource_likes,
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'POST',
      success: (data) => {
        $('.sidebar .like-btn a').attr({
            class: '',
            href: `/resource_likes/${data.like_id}`,
        })
        $('.sidebar .like-btn a').attr('data-method', 'delete')
      }
    })
  })
```

Or you can use event delegation to make a dynamic binding.

```
$('.sidebar .like-btn').on('click', '.like[data-method=post]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    $.ajax({
      url: /resource_likes,
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'POST',
      success: (data) => {
        $('.sidebar .like-btn a').attr({
            class: '',
            href: `/resource_likes/${data.like_id}`,
        })
        $('.sidebar .like-btn a').attr('data-method', 'delete')
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: I implemented the latter one. Thank you, Barmar.

Comment: My favorite is event delegation, very well explained.